# How to determine for what reasons it is impossible to update the application through google play?

Tags: android, google-play, samsung

Now, when some users try to update the application through Google Play, the message "This app is no linger compatible with your device. Contact the developers for more info" is displayed.

I am a developer, and my application does not have any obvious limitations. The minimum version SDK is 24 target 33. This is reported by users, for example, with devices "Samsung tab s7 +" Android 13 (SDK 33) or "Galaxy tab a7" Android 12 (SDK 32).

I'll clarify the question. I want to know not how the user can understand for what reasons this could happen. And how can the developer find out for what specific reason this happened on a particular device.